On a property of subobjects of infinite direct sums in categories
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a category with (arbitrary) coproducts (denoted as direct sums), a zero object, and in which monomorphisms are stable under coproducts. I am interested in additive categories, so feel free to add this assumption.
Consider the following property:
M. If $T \subseteq \bigoplus_{i \in I} A_i$ is a subobject and $B_i \subseteq A_i$ are subobjects such that each $T \hookrightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in I} A_i \xrightarrow{p_i} A_i$ factors through $B_i$, then $T \subseteq \bigoplus_{i \in I} B_i$. Here, notice that $\bigoplus_{i \in I} B_i \subseteq \bigoplus_{i \in I} A_i$ by assumption on $\mathcal{A}$.
Clearly M is satisfied in the category of modules over a ring, or more generally modules over a sheaf of rings. It also holds in $\mathbf{Set}_*$. I believe that M is wrong in general. Namely, we require the existence of a morphism into a direct sum, which is always difficult, in the categorical setting. Still, I find it is not so easy to construct a counterexample. In fact, I have used M in a proof without noticing it!
So my questions are:

What is an example of an additive category where M fails?
Is there already a common name for the property M?
What are more common (exactness) properties on $\mathcal{A}$ that imply M?
For example, is M satisfied in every AB5 abelian category?

I think 4 is true because of $$T = \mathrm{colim}_{E \subseteq I \text{ finite}} ~ T \cap \bigoplus_{i \in E} A_i$$
and the finite case (see below).
There is a somewhat similar property saying that $\bigoplus_{i \in I} B_i \to \prod_{i \in I} B_i$ is a monomorphism (if the product exists), but I am not sure if this is connected to M. Notice that it is always true that if $T \subseteq \prod_{i \in I} A_i$ is a subobject such that each $T \to A_i$ factors through $B_i$, then $T \subseteq \prod_{i \in I} B_i$. This is purely formal. This also means that in additive categories M is true for finite index sets $I$.
For 3 it seems like "pullbacks are stable under filtered colimits" is sufficient?

I don't have time to write a full answer just now, but I think the opposite category of abelian groups is an example where M fails. Take $I$ be the set of primes, $A_p=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, $B_p=0$ and $T=\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer to Question 1.
Following the comment by Jeremy Rickard, we can look what the condition is saying in $\mathcal{A}^{op}$ for an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, using the dualization principle but also that quotients correspond to subobjects via kernels in $\mathcal{A}$. The condition becomes: If $K \subseteq \prod_{i \in I} A_i$ is a subobject, and $C_i \subseteq A_i$ are subobjects with $\iota_i(C_i) \subseteq K$ for all $i$, then $\prod_{i \in I} C_i \subseteq K$. And this fails for $\mathcal{A} = \mathbf{Ab}$, already when $C_i = A_i$. Just take $K = \bigoplus_{i \in I} A_i$.
